# To construct a Möbius transformation to map a square to a unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

To map a square to a unit disk, I consider the Möbius transformation because the Möbius transformation maps circles and lines to circles and lines. And because the Möbius transformation can be determined uniquely by three points, I assign $z_1=-1+i$  to $\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $z_2=i$ to $i$ and $z_3=1+i$ to  $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ . And, I think by completing the four fragments of a square in a similar way, I can obtain the transformation.

> However, the computation is so complicated. Is there another simpler method? Thank you!

Comment: Mobius transformations also preserve angles in the whole plane. Therefore the images of the perpendicular sides of the square will have to become cirles/lines that are also perpendicular. They wouldn't become a single circle, which forms angle 0 with itself.

Comment: Oh! Yes! I forgot this. Then how do I solve this problem....?

Comment: One way to do it is using a [Schwarz-Christoffel transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping) In that page they even have the example of mapping the square to the upper half-plane. Then you could just use that and compose with a Mobius that maps the upper half-plane to the disc.

Comment: @LB_O The example maps the upper half plane to a square. But thank you anyway.

Comment: What do you mean "anyway"? That solves your problem completely, plus you learn how to solve the problem for any polygon. You can compose that one with a Mobius that maps the upper half-plane to the disc. This gives you one from the disc to the square.

Comment: @LB_O But what I need seems to be a transformation from square to upper-plane and then compose it with a Möbius transformation?!

Comment: @LB_O If I view this problem reversely, then I can apply the Schwarz -Christoffel transformation and map the disk to a square. And I just need to take the inverse, though the inverse of a S-C map seems to be complicated. I think I have solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this by a Mobius transformation.

But you can use elliptic functions. If your square is the unit
square with opposite vertices at $0$ and $1+i$, consider the lattice
generated by $2$ and $2i$. The Weierstrass $\wp$-function associated
to that lattice will map the interior of the square conformally to
a half plane. Then a Mobius transformation will take that to the disc.